# How can I dynamically create and add tags in PowerShell script during Invoke-Pester command?

Tags: powershell, tags, pester

I have several Describe/It tests in a ps1 file called Behavior.Tests.ps1. Each test, however, can only run successfully on systems with specific hardware.
I am aware that I can use tags like this in the Invoke-Pester command:

```
Invoke-Pester $path -Tag "Acceptance" -ExcludeTag "Flaky", "Slow", "LinuxOnly"
```

But I cannot count on the user to know the specifics of their hardware and choose the correct -Tag and -ExcludeTag to include. What I would rather do for my workflow is simply have `Invoke-Pester .\Behavior.Tests.ps1`, and then in the script have code like this that would get hardware info and build the right list of Tags and ExcludeTags:

```
if ($currentHardware -in $HardwareList) {
    $ExcludeTag += $TagFlaky
}
```

Then I would have a list of Tags and ExcludeTags before the first Describe/It that would run the right tests in the entire ps1 file. Is this possible in v5 Pester? I tried to debug and find the argument -Tag to modify it, but I could not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a wrapper PowerShell script that determines the tags prior to calling `Invoke-Pester` and then you can use that to Invoke Pester with the required tags.

For example:

```
$ComputerInfo = Get-ComputerInfo

$OS = switch ($ComputerInfo.WindowsProductName) {
    { $_ -match 'Windows 10' } { 'Win10' }
    { $_ -match 'Windows 8' { { 'Win8' }
    { $_ -match 'Linux' } { 'Linux' }
}

$Processor = switch ($ComputerInfo.CsProcessors.Name) {
    { $_ -match 'Intel' } { 'Intel' }
    { $_ -match 'ARM' } { 'ARM' }
}

Invoke-Pester $Path -Tag $OS,$Processor
```